# Making STL file of different geometries (Sphere, Cylinder, Ellipsoid) in Python?

Tags: python, shapes, point-clouds, stl-format

I am trying to make an **STL file** of different shapes such as **sphere, cylinder, ellipsoid**, etc. in python. I have heard of creating point clouds and then creating an STL from there but could not find any specific details yet. If I have **a cylinder of different **height** and radius** or a **sphere of different radius** or an **ellipsoid of different semiaxis lengths (xr,yr,zr)**, how do I create them?

I am relatively new in Python and using Spyder (Python 3.8) for my codes. Would really appreciate it if anyone could help or forward me in the right direction.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. You *may* be able to get help on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange, but *please* read through their [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) **first** to ensure your question is on topic there.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)), the STL format is simple and well enough documented. The hard part is how you want to approximate your non plane surface with triangles, but this is mathematics (geometry) and not Python code. As your volumes are simple, just imagine a regular grid on the surface of the volume, and build your triangles from that. For a earth analogy, you could  take points regularly placed on parallels (same latitude). It should be possible *by hand*...